# PHP XPath - how to get value from result

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I have the followng XML file from Ebay

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GeteBayDetailsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2012-07-04T12:02:14.541Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Success</Ack>
    <Version>779</Version>
    <Build>E779_INTL_BUNDLED_14986004_R1</Build>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>US</Site>
        <SiteID>0</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Canada</Site>
        <SiteID>2</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>UK</Site>
        <SiteID>3</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Germany</Site>
        <SiteID>77</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Australia</Site>
        <SiteID>15</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>France</Site>
        <SiteID>71</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>eBayMotors</Site>
        <SiteID>100</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Italy</Site>
        <SiteID>101</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Netherlands</Site>
        <SiteID>146</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Spain</Site>
        <SiteID>186</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>India</Site>
        <SiteID>203</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>HongKong</Site>
        <SiteID>201</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Singapore</Site>
        <SiteID>216</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Malaysia</Site>
        <SiteID>207</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Philippines</Site>
        <SiteID>211</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>CanadaFrench</Site>
        <SiteID>210</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Poland</Site>
        <SiteID>212</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Belgium_Dutch</Site>
        <SiteID>123</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Belgium_French</Site>
        <SiteID>23</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Austria</Site>
        <SiteID>16</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Switzerland</Site>
        <SiteID>193</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <SiteDetails>
        <Site>Ireland</Site>
        <SiteID>205</SiteID>
        <DetailVersion>1</DetailVersion>
        <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
    </SiteDetails>
    <UpdateTime>2009-07-09T10:48:17.000Z</UpdateTime>
</GeteBayDetailsResponse>
```

I need to get the value of node SiteID where the node Site matches whatever variable I pass.  The code I have is:

```
$xml_file ='SiteDetails.xml';
$xmlDoc = new DomDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml_file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xmlDoc);

$siteIDList =  $xpath->query("/GeteBayDetailsResponse/SiteDetails[Site=$site]/SiteID");

var_dump($siteIDList);
echo $siteIDList->SiteID;
```

I get the following result:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#11 (0) {
}
```

Can anyone help?  I want to get a value of 3.

Comment: Generally with long XML strings (or code, of course) it is better to format it nicely nested prior to pasting, so it is readable for everyone `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to surround `$site` with quotes and add namespace:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('ebay', 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');

$siteIDList = $xpath->query("/ebay:GeteBayDetailsResponse/ebay:SiteDetails[ebay:Site='$site']/ebay:SiteID");
```

Just to be sure, can give us the `$site` value which gives you this result?

**Edit:** Added namespace as Vaman Kulkarni suggested.

Comment: This XPath will not work as the xml contains default namespace. Namespace should be considered while forming XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Used API `registerNamespace` from Florent's answer.

Your XML file contains default namespace. Hence you can register a variable name like `ebay` against default namespace (`urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents`) like below in your code and the use following xpath

`$xpath->registerNamespace('ebay', 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents');`

`$siteIDList = $xpath->query("//ebay:Site[text()='$site']/following-sibling::ebay:SiteID/text()");`

**OR**

you can use following XPATH, which will not require any extra code other than evaluating it :-)

`//*[namespace-uri()='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents' and name()='Site' and text()='$site']/following-sibling::*[namespace-uri()='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents' and name()='SiteID']/text()`

**Note:** $site is the runtime value of `<Site>` node of which **value of `<SiteID>`** will be matched.

Comment: Not sure I understand, I have tried your first option and get the same result as I got the first time round, ie.  object(DOMNodeList)#11 (0) { 
}  I want the value of <siteID> not an object

Comment: Both the Xpaths return value of the node `<SiteID>` as `/text()` at the end of the xpath will match the value of the node

Comment: How do I access the value of the node?  What am I missing :/

Comment: @LeeTee You should retrive value by writing something like this `$siteIDList->item(0)->$nodeValue` to get the value of `<SiteID>` node.